# Subset Counting question

Tags: combinatorics

How many subsets of [20] consist of 3 odd integers and any number of even integers?

This question was asked in an interview today and I wasn't able to solve it.

Please help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to choose exactly 3 odd integers, so you choose out of the 10 odds ${10\choose 3}$ and then you want to decide whether or not to include any of the evens so for each even there are 2 options, giving $2^{10}$. Therefore total is ${10\choose 3}\times 2^{10}$.

Answer (score 3):

There are $10$ odd integers from which we pick $3$, and $10$ even integers from which we pick any subset. Hence the count is
$$ {10\choose 3}\cdot 2^{10}.$$